# How to pipe data from an ongoing process to a python script for processing

Tags: python, pipe

I'm trying to develop a gui in python to replace the output of a command line program that a team I've been working with is using. At a high level, the program I'm trying to replace reads a bunch of sensors from a board and then outputs their values to the command line terminal as a bunch of fields followed by a value. This is annoying currently because it frequently jumps around and isn't user friendly. I want to directly take the output of the board reading program and pipe it into my python program that will strip the fields and values and update a gui accordingly. The gui seems to be working fine on its own but I'm running into some issues with the python program hanging when it first starts running when piped into. I know that there are much better ways to get the output of the board into the gui, but for now, assume that I only have access to the console output from the program that prints the values to console.

Here's a snippet of code that can illustrate my example:

Bash spammer to simulate the readings

```
#!/bin/ksh

while : 
do
  echo ' - Sensor_1_reading: 21'
  sleep 2
  echo ' - Sensor_2_reading: 32'
  sleep 2
  echo ' - Sensor_3_reading: 232'
  sleep 2
done
```

Function within my main-gui.py program

```
    def update_function(self):
        print("Running Update!")
        if not sys.stdin.isatty():
            print("Trying to read")
            line = sys.stdin.read()
            print(line)
            
        else:
            print("Nothing on stdin")
```

Whenever I run the following command on Ubuntu using WSL2 `source spammer.sh | python main-gui.py`, I get a print out of "running update" and then "trying to read" which then hangs. Sending a keyboard interrupt seems to kill the spammer at which point the python program will run fine and the gui will appear. I've looked for other solutions and I've made sure that I set my PYTHONUNBUFFERED env variable as that could apparently cause issues. Making python unbuffered didn't help. It seems like it might also be related to the fact that stdin needs an EOF character before it will produce any input. Is there anyway to get the python program to ingest what there is on stdin without waiting for an EOF? Any other suggestions on how I could approach this problem?

Comment: Use the *input()* function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the ksh script exactly as shown in the question (let's call it sensor.sh) and a Python script named Jul13.py as follows:

```
while (s := input()):
    print(s)
```

...then...

```
./sensor.sh | python Jul13.py
```

...will generate...

```
- Sensor_1_reading: 21
- Sensor_2_reading: 32
- Sensor_3_reading: 232
- Sensor_1_reading: 21
- Sensor_2_reading: 32
- Sensor_3_reading: 232
```

*ad infinitum*

Comment: Thanks for the quick and easy answer. Don't know why this didn't pop up when I first started looking into this.